# App Invites with Facebook on iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook

I'm trying to set up App Invites on an iOS app I developed. However, when I invite others to use the app, they do not get any notifications.

Right now, the App Link I obtained redirects me to a link starting with itunes.apple.com, but the screen is blank. In addition, when I run the didCompleteWith Results function, I get "didComplete = 1;". I am not sure why the invitation is not working and why the person on the other end is not getting a notification. I have a hunch it could have to do with my App Link, but I am honestly not sure at all. I am trying to use Facebook's purely Mobile API since I do not have a website for my app. Also, it is not released on the App Store.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: But you're doing what exactly? Just post to your Facebook wall or sending someone a message using Graph? I don't fully understand from your description where exactly is a problem - that the link doesn't work or that your friend isn't receiving the link?

Comment: No, I am using App Invite, which is a screen that let's users select friends to share an App with. However, the users on the other side do not get a notification that I have shared the App with them. I am not using Graph, or posting to a Facebook wall, or sending a message using Messenger -- those are different processes I believe.

Comment: As far as I remember, the link is not working as long as your app is not available in the AppStore. I hope I'm not mistaken. As for why App Invite is not working, you'd have to post some code, because atm there is nothing to check why it's not working properly. Also I won't help with this matter, as I've never used that App Invite. Hope you get an answer soon ^^.

Comment: Thanks! For now I'm not going to worry about it until I post the app to the app store. If that solve it, great. If not, I'll look into it further later.

Comment: If I am not mistaken people can choose not to get notified by turning off the notifications in the Facebook app settings. Just make sure that the notifications are turned on for the user that you are testing with so that they can receive notifications.